# Symfony: The class XYZ was not found in the chain configured namespaces

Tags: symfony

Existing questions did not help.
I am still learning Symfony and setting up an existing project. Trying to run doctrine fixtures from my application directory.

```
./app/console doctrine:fixtures:load --env test
```

And running this gives me following errors

> Error thrown while running command "doctrine:fixtures:load --env test --em default". Message: "The class 'ClientPortal\GenericBundle\Document\Accountant' was not found in the chain configured namespaces _XyzProjectName\CalendarContext\Domain\Model, Integration\GetFeedbackBundle\Model, _XyzProjectName\AccountingProcessContext\Domain\Model, _XyzProjectName\CaseContext\Domain" {"exception":"[object] (Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException(code: 0): The class 'ClientPortal\GenericBundle\Document\Accountant' was not found in the chain configured namespaces _XyzProjectName\CalendarContext\Domain\Model, Integration\GetFeedbackBundle\Model, _XyzProjectName\AccountingProcessContext\Domain\Model, _XyzProjectName\CaseContext\Domain at /usr/local/var/www/1800-api/vendor/doctrine/persistence/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/MappingException.php:22)

And this exception is being thrown when trying to persist object of class

> 'ClientPortal\GenericBundle\Document\Accountant'

and here is my doctrine in config.yml

```
doctrine:
dbal:
    driver:   pdo_pgsql
    host:     '%database_host%'
    dbname:   '%database_name%'
    user:     '%database_user%'
    password: '%database_password%'
orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
    auto_mapping: true
    mappings:
        CalendarBundle:
            prefix: '_XyzProjectName\CalendarContext\Domain\Model'
        IntegrationGetFeedbackBundle:
            prefix: 'Integration\GetFeedbackBundle\Model'
        AccountingProcessBundle:
            prefix: '_XyzProjectName\AccountingProcessContext\Domain\Model'
        CaseBundle:
            prefix: '_XyzProjectName\CaseContext\Domain'
        GenericBundle:
            type: "annotation"   
            prefix: 'ClientPortal\GenericBundle\Document'
            dir: 'src'
            is_bundle: false
```

The snippet which is raising this exception

```
    $account = new ClientPortal\GenericBundle\Document\Accountant();//full namespace added for clarity - also this file lies in the same directory structure. 
    $account->setSfAccountantId($accountantId);
    $account->setUsername($username);
    $manager = new ObjectManager;
    $manager->persist( $account ); //This throws the above mentioned exception
```

My thought is, the file ClientPortal\GenericBundle\Document\Accountant.php is being autoloaded as there is no exception thrown at the time of instantion of its object. But, there is something missing with configuration or mapping because of which doctrine does not know how to persist its object.

[Source code][1] Accountant class

GenericBundle(s) registered under AppKernel

```
new Website\GenericBundle\WebsiteGenericBundle(),
new Admin\GenericBundle\AdminGenericBundle(),
new ClientPortal\GenericBundle\ClientPortalGenericBundle(),
new TaxApp\GenericBundle\TaxAppGenericBundle(),
```

Comment: Hi, did you tried to add `ClientPortal\GenericBundle\Document` to the `mappings` section in doctrine config?

Comment: We know nothing about ClientPortal\GenericBundle\Document configuration. Please provide more info.

Comment: @EugeneR Yes, I have tried adding it there. Can you suggest your way with exact the exact syntax?

Comment: @vytsci Hey, I was not sure what exactly you need there. But I have added some info around the invocation of respective methods and directory structure. Let me know if you need anything.

Comment: @Aman ClientPortal\GenericBundle\Document like EugeneR suggested try adding this to a mapping. Because it has no Entity namespace so doctrine is unable to see it.

Comment: @vytsci I am still new to Symfony can you suggest me with the exact syntax? And it is to be added in config.yml under ORM settings right?

Comment: @Aman you have pasted you ORM config under mappings you already have several entities, consider adding one more, but I think you should reconsider rewriting entities under Entity namespace, so your entities could be automatically mapped.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189932/discussion-between-aman-and-vytsci).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, as I suggested in comments - try to add `ClientPortal\GenericBundle\Document\` namespace to mappings in your doctrine config file, like that:

```
#...
orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
    mappings:
        # ...
        ClientPortalGenericBundle:
            type: annotation
            prefix: 'ClientPortal\GenericBundle\Document\'
            dir: '%kernel.root_dir%/src/ClientPortal/GenericBundle/Document/'
            #is_bundle: false
    auto_mapping: true
```

Comment: Well, I have tried that earlier. And it throws "Unknown bundle GenericBundle or not enabled"

Comment: I tried adding that. Updated the config in question and this is the error thrown now
 `Class "ClientPortal\GenericBundle\Document\Accountant" is not a valid entity or mapped super class." {"exception`

Comment: Thanks man. It worked. I had to add couple of other configuration properties as well like type, prefix and dir.

Comment: @Aman, glad to be helpful. Can you please provide this additional parameters you added - I will add it in the answer

Comment: I am still digging in. Maybe I was confused. It still isn't working. About the additional parameter you can see them in the question. I have updated the configuration in question.

Comment: @Aman so the `dir` must be smth like that `%kernel.root_dir%/src/ClientPortal/GenericBundle/Document/` , also, try to comment `auto_mapping` parameter. I will edit an answer now

Comment: This is what I am getting right now with and without auto_mapping: true
`Class "ClientPortal\GenericBundle\Document\Accountant" is not a valid entity or mapped super class`

Comment: So, please, update the question with source code of Accountant class

Comment: I have added a link to the mentioned source code. Thanks once again.

Comment: Hey, did you registered GenericBundle in the AppKernel.php file?

Comment: I have added the bundle registration in the question. There are four.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190301/discussion-between-eugene-ruban-and-aman).

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue with Symfony 4 while using multiple database connections. This one https://stackoverflow.com/a/55361742/2540699 helped me to solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I bumped into this kind of message in my Symfony 6.1 project, using multiple entity managers, with one of the entity managers specified as default in `doctrine.yaml`:

```yaml
doctrine:
    orm:
        default_entity_manager: general
        entity_managers:
          general:
            # config for general
          other_entity_manager:
            # config for other entity manager
```

Everything was fine on my dev environment, but on production I got the error

> Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException: "The class *XXX* was not found in the chain configured namespaces " at /opt/approot/current/vendor/doctrine/persistence/src/Persistence/Mapping/MappingException.php

Problem seemed to be that I have a `when@prod:` section in my `doctrine.config.yml`. It seems I had to repeat the `default_entity_manager` over there:

```yaml
when@prod:
    doctrine:
        orm:
            default_entity_manager: general
            # other prod-specific configuration
```

This fixed it for me.

Update: This is probably related to this issue: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/27769